# Doesn't show list that I show with right click in JavaScript after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I use the below JavaScript code to show a list when the user right-clicks on a GridView's row and the GridView is in an UpdatePanel. When postback occurs, it doesn't show the list.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //--------------- Info Box --------------------
    $('.CityItem').mouseup(function (e) {
       if ( e.which === 3 ) {
          $('.CityItem').children('.CompanyList').hide();
          $(this).children('.CompanyList').toggle();

          $(this).children('.CompanyList').css('top', e.pageY - 300 );
          $(this).children('.CompanyList').css('left', e.pageX - 175 );
       }
       e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.CityItem').hover( function () {
       $(this).children('.CompanyList').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Attach a handler to the load event.
Sys.Application.add_load(applicationLoadHandler);
```

Put the handler(above code) inside the updatePanel.Then applicationLoadHandler will get excuted when update panel refresh.

```
function applicationLoadHandler() {
   //--------------- Info Box --------------------
    $(document).on('mouseup', '.CityItem', function (e) {
       if ( e.which === 3 ) {
          $('.CityItem').children('.CompanyList').hide();
          $(this).children('.CompanyList').toggle();

          $(this).children('.CompanyList').css('top', e.pageY - 300 );
          $(this).children('.CompanyList').css('left', e.pageX - 175 );
       }
       e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).on('hover', '.CityItem',function () {
       $(this).children('.CompanyList').hide();
    });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you,works but change first line of function to $('.CityItem').mouseup(function (e)

Answer (score 0):

This because the elements are added again after completion of ajax call but document.ready is not fired again. The could be solved by event delegation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //--------------- Info Box --------------------
    $(document).on('mouseup', '.CityItem', function (e) {
       if ( e.which === 3 ) {
          $('.CityItem').children('.CompanyList').hide();
          $(this).children('.CompanyList').toggle();

          $(this).children('.CompanyList').css('top', e.pageY - 300 );
          $(this).children('.CompanyList').css('left', e.pageX - 175 );
       }
       e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).on('hover', '.CityItem',function () {
       $(this).children('.CompanyList').hide();
    });
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery Api](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

You can also re-bind the event to added elements when ajax request end using [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager endRequest Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler)


function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)           
{
    if (args.get_error() != undefined)
    {
        bindEvents(); 
    }
}

function bindEvents()
{
     //--------------- Info Box --------------------
    $('.CityItem').mouseup(function (e) {
       if ( e.which === 3 ) {
          $('.CityItem').children('.CompanyList').hide();
          $(this).children('.CompanyList').toggle();

          $(this).children('.CompanyList').css('top', e.pageY - 300 );
          $(this).children('.CompanyList').css('left', e.pageX - 175 );
       }
       e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.CityItem').hover( function () {
       $(this).children('.CompanyList').hide();
    });

}

$(document).ready(function () {
   bindEvents(); 
});
```